# Avoid logging empty commands in Bash

Tags: bash, syslog, rsyslog

I am using the following lines at the end of my .bashrc file to log entered bash commands to Syslog:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='
RETRN_VAL=$?;
if [ -f /tmp/lastoutput.tmp ]; then
    LAST_OUTPUT=$(cat /tmp/lastoutput.tmp);
    rm /tmp/lastoutput.tmp;
fi;
logger -S 10000 -p local6.debug "{\"user\": \"$(whoami)\", \"path\": \"$(pwd)\", \"pid\": \"$$\", \"b64_command\": \"$(history 1 | sed "s/^[ ]*[09]\+[ ]*//"| base64 -w0 )\", \"status\": \"$RETRN_VAL\", \"b64_output\": \"$LAST_OUTPUT\"}";
unset LAST_OUTPUT;
logoutput() {
    output=$(while read input; do echo "$input"; done < "${1:-/dev/stdin}");
    echo -e "$output\n";
    echo -e "$output" | head -c 10000 | base64 -w0 > /tmp/lastoutput.tmp;
    return $?;
}
```

The problem I am having is that whenever I open a new shell or simply hit Enter without entering any command it is logging the latest history entry at that time. How can I avoid logging empty commands or simply logging them as a blank line?
Thanks!

Comment: You may be interested in `auditd` instead